# SSRS Report automatic page navigation/looping

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a SSRS report that has 7 pages that I would like to have loop from beginning to end and then refresh every few minutes. Is this possible? I have been searching, but cannot find anything on how to do it. I have SQL Server 2008.
Thank you!

Comment: What is your deployment scenario? Report Manager, SharePoint, Windows Form, Web?

Comment: Sorry, I just took this over from someone who left. This is published to the web via http. http://<sqlserver>/reports/<environment/pages/.aspx.

Comment: That sounds like Report Manager although I cant be sure as you have butchered that URL.  If you go the target page and click the Help link at top right, and the Help page starts with "Reporting Services Report Manager", then it is Report Manager.

Comment: Yes it is report manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set the AutoRefresh property on the Report object, using BIDS/Visual Studio.  This is in seconds so a value of 120 = 2 minutes.

Comment: Won't this only refresh the first main page? I saw the auto refresh property on the report itself, and when I set it to 15 seconds, it just kept refreshing the main page and would not loop through all the pages. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You are correct - I didnt understand your full requirement.

Comment: What I would like to have happen is that the report navigate from page 1 to page 7 automatically and then start over or do a refresh. This report is going onto a TV mounted on the wall and the team would like to see the pages loop through. The only way I have found is to build a custom silver light app, but was hoping there might be an easier way. Right now the report has a page break for each Project Manager, so they get their own page. I am open to any other options that might make the automatic scrolling feasible.

Comment: In SQL Server Reporting Services, we can set the report to refresh automatically based on a specific time interval. However, it is not supported to set the report to jump to the next page in a loop at the same time.

Comment: Nowadays I would look at python selenium and chromedriver - with minimal scripting you can launch a chrome browser and automate browser navigation actions etc.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Reporting Services, we can set the report to refresh automatically based on a specific time interval. However, it is not supported to set the report to jump to the next page in a loop at the same time. I recommend you submit your suggestion to the Microsoft Connect at http://connect.microsoft.com/. Your feedback is valuable for Microsoft to improve products and increase the level of service provide