# Can I activate an action in SSRS via expression instead of clicking?

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

Short background: I'm trying to configure a SSRS report so that it moves to the next page automatically every x seconds(for a dashboard). Since there isn't such a feature in SSRS I try to build a workaround. I track the passed time and now I want to use it as a variable to activate an action to jump to a bookmark.

**So the question is, how can I write an expression that activates the action of an object as if I were clicking it? Is that even possible?**

Alternatively: Is there another way to move the next page in a report triggered by refresh or time?

Answer (score 0):

You can only refresh Dataset i.e Report and not move to next page, This is not supported in SSRS.

Here are 2 threads which describes the same

[Thread 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/efb149ff-4ad8-40b3-a75c-fbf9e18b8a5e/ssrs-how-to-move-to-next-page-in-ssrs-report-using-auto-refresh?forum=sqlreportingservices)

[Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375369/ssrs-report-automatic-page-navigation-looping)

Comment: Thanks, but I already found these threads. That's why I'm trying that workaround. My question is simply, can I activate actions via expression? Like eg. I have a textbox "TB1" with the action "Go to bookmark" and somewhere else an expression like "if timediff = 3 : TB1.action.activate()" (Not the correct syntax, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in the past by hiding sections of the report based on the counter/position in the 'loop'. I did this with subreports but you could achieve the same by hiding a group based on a counter.

As I was doing a few of these, I setup a table that stored the report name, the number of positions in the loop and the current position. At the start of the dataset query I would increment the position counter.

The reports would be set to auto-refresh every 30 seconds. When the report refreshed, it would increase the counter by one. The section/subreport/group hidden expression would evaluate the position and switch visibility on or off accordingly.

Comment: That sounds promising, I will try that. Thanks!